# How to Copy HTML and CSS of a particular webite from google chrome

Tags: css

I have done many Moves to get Get Direct CSS form website in google chrome but i failed. So tell me how to get it.

Answer (score 0):

use view page source and in the opening window find the linking to the css right click it and open it in a new window you can copy it from there

for example in stackoverflow

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=c9958f49ae3f">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a mac so it may be different for you. Try right-clicking on the page. Then select 'view page source' from the list. The chrome will open a new tab with the source code inside. From there you can even open the external css and js files. At this point just copy and paste the code. To view a certain elements source code just choose 'inspect element' and click on the element of which you wish to see the css. Then (even though the styles are beside checkboxes it still lets you highlight them) copy and paste those.